# Checkbox with div.span is not clicking

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to click the checkbox in a result table on the webpage, it is a typical selection column of that row. But it does not click on it. I have tried all possible ways by checking with direct isSelected(), type checking and even javascript executor option too. Could you please let me know whats wrong in my code? also please suggest with workable answer.

**The respective html code**.

```
<tbody id="frmResults:USTTaxTableId_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
    <tr data-ri="0" data-rk="123456789" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-selectable" role="row" aria-selected="false">
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-selection-column">
            <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="frmResults:USTTaxTableId_checkbox" aria-checked="false">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                    <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-active-state">0003784</td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-active-state">09/21/2017</td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-active-state">09/21/2017</td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-active-state"/>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My script is...

```
WebElement row = ele.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr[data-ri=\"" + row_num + "\"]"));
String isSelected = row.getAttribute("aria-selected");

scenario.write("isSelected is : " + isSelected);

//WebElement rowCheckBox = row.findElement(By.className("ui-selection-column"));
WebElement rowCheckBox = row.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class=\"ui-selection-column\"]"));

if (isSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
    WebElement box = rowCheckBox.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div[2]"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) browser;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", box);
    isSelected = row.getAttribute("aria-selected");
    scenario.write("isSelected in inside is : " + isSelected);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL you are testing with?

Comment: @Christine, sorry, it is my enterprise application and so i cannot expose it here.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on `input type="checkbox"` instead of `span`?

Comment: i tried with `rowCheckBox.findElement(By.xpath("/input[@type=\"checkbox\"]"))`, but it throws me that `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` error.

Comment: Try this `WebElement rowCheckBox = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='ui-selection-column']//input[contains(@name,'USTTaxTableId_checkbox')]"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be that page not loaded. Use `WebDriverWait` and try to wait for clickability of the `checkbox`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement row = ele.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr[data-ri=" + row_num + "]"));
String isSelected = row.getAttribute("aria-selected");
scenario.write("isSelected is : " + isSelected);

if (isSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(row.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-chkbox-box")))).click();

    isSelected = row.getAttribute("aria-selected");
    scenario.write("isSelected in inside is : " + isSelected);
}
```

If will not work add code below before click:

```
wait.until(d -> ((JavascriptExecutor) d)
        .executeScript("return document.readyState !== 'loading'"));
```

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm. can you please help me understand the `readyState` code. What exactly it does? please...

Comment: [The Document.readyState property describes the loading state of the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)